# How can I trap "View Report" in ReportViewer (webforms) for SSRS?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I am using `ReportViewer.WebForms` in `asp.net` page. I have the parameter toolbar showing up where I can select a parameter, it does a postback to get the next parameter (dependent on the first), and so forth.

When I click the `View Report` button there is a postback and the report will display fine.

All this works great.

What I would like to do is set the `ShowReportBody` to false

```
ReportViewer.ShowReportBody = False
```

At this point I would like to grab all the parameters that have been selected by the user and run the render method to export to a file (of my choosing .. maybe excel, maybe `pdf` .. does not really matter, nor is the topic of this question).

So, my question is, how (or can I) trap the button event of the `View Report` button? I would like to be able to use the `ReportViewer` UI in order to capture all the parameters instead of building custom parameters.

I'd also like to rename this, but, again .. another topic :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IsPostBack` flag and `QueryString`

Example:

```
Viewer.ShowReportBody = false

if(IsPostBack)
{
    if(Request.QueryString["Exec"] = "Auto")
        Viewer.ShowReportBody = true;
    ...
}
else
{
    Viewer.ShowReportBody = true;
}
```